# multiprocessing with python-bioformats reader?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, bioinformatics, jpype

I have a code that I want parallelized. It generally goes like this:

```
import javabridge as jb
import bioformats as bf
from google.cloud import storage
import tempfile

def process_image(blob):
    storage_client = storage.Client() 
    bucket = storage_client.bucket("lab_olympus_images")

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
        filename = tmp_dir + '/' + blob.split('/')[-1]
        blob = bucket.blob(blob)
        blob.download_to_filename(filename)
        with bf.ImageReader(filename, perform_init=True) as rdr:
            imagearray = rdr.read(c=0, z=0, t=0)
    eightbit = (255*imagearray).astype(np.uint8)
    # process images with opencv
    results = process(eightbit)
        
    return results

blobs = [blob.name for blob in storage.Client().list_blobs("bucket_name")]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jb.start_vm(class_path.bf.JARS)
    with get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
        output = pool.map(process_image, blobs)
    jb.kill_vm()
```

I think I have boiled down the issue with javabridge.
What I have tried:

1.) like mentioned in this github issue: https://github.com/LeeKamentsky/python-javabridge/issues/176, I have tried to start and kill the VM inside my function. It works on the first iteration, but fails on the next job.

2.)I have tried to use the solution from this github issue: https://github.com/LeeKamentsky/python-javabridge/issues/181, but shared memory runs only one at a time (I can tell because it only makes one temp folder at a time).

```
with parallel_backend("multiprocessing", n_jobs=num_cores):
    output = Parallel(require='sharedmem')(delayed(QC)(i) for i in inputs)
```

3.) I have tried this as well:

```
output = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(QC)(i, jb, bf) for i in inputs)
```

It fails similarily to #1.

is their a work around to this issue with javabridge?

would Jpype work with python-bioformats and how would I use it for multiprocessing?

I'm on the verge of giving up and trying to rewrite everything in Java.